# csrf in react and rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, csrf

I want to use csrf token while using post request. For that in api controller I have used `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` at the top.

But how should I use that in react.

Also I could not found any good article on this.

```
fetch('/api/v1/posts', {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify(postdata),
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, you need to pass the X-CSRF-TOKEN as a header to Rails when making the call. You can use `document.querySelector('[name="csrf-token"]').content` to get the token:

This should be in your `componentDidMount` method:

```
   fetch('/api/v1/posts', {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify(postdata),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': document.querySelector('[name="csrf-token"]').content
      },
    })
```

Comment: I am using fetch

Comment: Ah OK, I'd recommend putting that in the question, along with an example of the code you're using to actually make the fetch call.